# Best way to render different fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I was searching the best-practice to implement a font inside a website and I still didn't found a real answer to this.

On forums and blogs many people say that using `@font-face` is the best way, other using **Typekit** or **Cufon**.

I don't like these 3 options.

**Font-face** render my fonts grainy.

**Typekit** is not freeware and do not have all the font that I'd like to use.

**Cufon** use canvas.

There are other way to implement fonts?

There is a way to render it with no grain?

---

Screenshots:

**Mac**
[image]

**Windows**
[image]

Comment: Can you add an image to explain what you mean by "grainy"?

Comment: I do not have images. But if you see any website that use it you will see it grainy. Seems with no anti-alias. Squared...

Comment: [startupsthisishowdesignworks.com](http://startupsthisishowdesignworks.com) looking at this for example. On windows is very grainy, on Mac no. How to render it on windows like on Mac?

Comment: Make a screenshot on Windows and on Mac, use an image editor to paste them alongside each other, so that we can see the effect. Chances are, it's a buggy preferences setting on Windows.

Comment: Have a look at your question. Can you see a difference between the two screenshots? I can't. You need to cut unimportant parts away from the screenshots and just leave the part of the screen which demonstrates what you want to show us.

Comment: Also: On which kind of Mac did you make the screenshot? What's the screen resolution for Win and Mac?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I see differences of rendering on S - P - O - H - E - G - N... if you don't is different. Btw Philipp is right. It just depend from OS. Nothing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font rendering depends on the Operation system, some of the font specific settings in the OS, the browser and the font itself. The better the font is prepared for screen usage (hinting,…) the better it looks. Their is no »do it like this and it is always fine way«, there are too many factors that play a role. In the images above you are trying to render very thin font, this is always problematic, especially if the font is badly hinted and/or set in a small size. The advantage of services like TypeKit and google webfonts are that they provide you with screen optimized fonts, so if you are not familiar with fonts themself you should prefer some prepared fonts, or optimize the font yourself if it is too bad. You should also keep in mind that not every font is suitable for screen usage and i think that can be one reason why google and typekit do not provide all fonts.

good luck…

**EDIT:**

once I forgot to enable some kind of font rendering option on windows, I think it was somewhere at: `leftclick computer > properties > performance`, but I am not sure where exactly, I do not use windows anymore to find it, but the start was at »leftclick computer > properties« and it was about the »antialiasing« of fonts. After ticking the box it looked much better. It was a thin font too in this case…

greetings…

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by 'grainy'?  I only ever see that in older versions of internet explorer, and there are CSS properties for font smoothing.

Using TypeKit uses `@font-face`, it's just loaded in a different way.  Have you tried Google's webfonts too?

Here is a great article on the best method to use: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot?') format('eot'), 
       url('GraublauWeb.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('GraublauWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Is the `?` after `.eot` intentional?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Just read the article at [the link](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/).  You'll see the `?` there too along with a detailed explanation.